# asp.net c# App using 2 clients

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is Bar bill creating app, and i want to block second client to create a bill for table 1 if first client is already creating bill for table 1. What is the best way to do it? I tried session but could not make it work.

http://postimg.org/image/qaeof6fix/

I managed to do solution with extra column in table, on button "add" column is set to true and on button order is set to false, dropdown list populates only with false values and its working, but if you start to add products and close the page before ordering column in database always stays true... i need something like "onPageLeave" to put column to false, is there such a thing?

Comment: write code on order button click  - > check same table already exist in table, then new bill cannot save

Comment: i want to block second only if they are creating a bill in the same time, this way blocks second ever creating a bill for table 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ways:

1. Add a nullable column named "CurrentClientId" to table, client can create bill only if CurrentClientId is null, then set it to null after check out.
2. Add a foreign table(ClientId, TableId, Status, CreatedTime, ...), client can create bill only if all of related records status are "Finished".

Hope that helps.

Comment: I managed to do first solution :D, on button "add" column is set to true and on button order is set to false, dropdown list populates only with false values and its working, but if you start to add products and close the page before ordering column in database always stays true... i need something like "onPageLeave" to put column to false, is there such a thing?

Comment: Hmm, an event is a good plus, but have you thought about "Disaster"?What about computer shut down suddenly(power off)? In real restaurant, if someone order a table and eating, and waiter will check to make sure clients are still eating if long time passed. so for network order, we have to show others I am still holding the table.

Comment: In addition to the "CurrentClientId" column, you need another column named "LastActiveTime", and set a timeout(eg. 10 mins), and client should update "LastActiveTime" of table every 1 min(up to you). if other clients see "CurrentClientId" of table is null or DateTime.Now - "LastActiveTime" > Timeout, the table is available!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Flag Column in Table to show its been created by client1. So when client2 selects it it will compare the value and give an alert to client2.